# jquery is not loaded from cdn in layout.ejs in sails.js

Tags: cdn, sails.js

I am trying sails.js but am confused. I need to use jquery and put it in the layout.ejs as CDN however it is not recognized in the view.

I am not using linker (is it a must?)

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Be careful NOT to put the link to the cdn between:

```
<!--SCRIPTS-->

<!--SCRIPTS END-->
```

or they will be overwritten by whatever is on the local /assets/linker/js (or assets/js in Sailsjs 0.10)